# al hacer consulta en mariadb se ejecuta y en mysql no

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Tengo el siguiente insert:

```
$bd->query("insert into test (cam_varchar,cam_text,cam_decimal,cam_int) values('hola','texto','','')");
```

y en mariadb si funciona correctamente aunque me muestra ciertos warnings pero igual ejecuta e inserta en la base de datos.

Pero al ejecutarlo en un phpmyadmin con mysql me sale que el campo cam_int no permite el valor `''` ya que no es un entero.

obviamente la solucion es validar que no sea un campo vacio y/o cambiarlo por un 0 de ser necesario pero la idea es que estoy migrando mi sistema de un servidor a otro y no tener que tocar mucho el codigo php.
No se que puedo estar haciendo mal
Nota:
e puesto valores por defecto en los campos, pero igual

Comment: estas yendo de la base A (que es un motor) a la base B (que es otro motor) por lo tanto, puede ser que tengas muchos errores, y las configuraciones de las bases sean diferentes... no es tirar todo asi como esta.. es ir revisando las cosas una por una... si te dice que '' no es un entero, tiene razon, ese campo no es un entero...

Comment: Intenta deshabilitando el [Modo Estricto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict).

Comment: @Sal como puedo hacer eso amigo, creo que por alli va la respuesta, si pudieras indicarme como hacerlo me ayudarias bastante

Comment: @gbianchi te entiendo y es logica tu respuesta amigo pero ambos son mysql maria db es solo una rama de mysql y en su documentacion dicen que todo lo que funciona en uno tambien funciona en lo otro

Comment: si.. pero si las configuraciones no son las mismas, no va a funcionar igual... y la base es la misma, pero no todo es igual....

Comment: Intenta con `SET SESSION sql_mode = '';`

Comment: @Sal en donde pongo eso amigo ? en consola de mysql (cpanel) o en mi codigo php ? (disculpa la ignorancia)

Comment: En php, una vez antes de los inserts.